# Please help me to solve my homework and correct my solution

Tags: measure-theory

Let $ Q\cap [0,1]=\{r_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$. For each $f\in C_0(R)$, define $I(f)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{f(r_n)}{2^n} +\int_0^1 fdm$, where m denotes the Lebesgue measure on R.

1. Show that $I$ is a bounded positive linear functional on $C_0(R)$ and determine $\| I \|$. Then show that there exists a Radon measure $\mu$ on $R~$ s.t  $~I(f)=\int_Rfd\mu$ for all $f\in C_0(R)$.
2. Put $~\nu=\mu-m$ and find $|\nu|$ and $~\| \nu\|$.
3. Determine $L^1(\nu)$.
4. If $\nu (~[0,1]^c)=0$, show that $\nu(~u\cap[0,1])>0~$ for any open set $u$ in $R$ with $u\cap[0,1]\neq 0$.

**My proof**:

1. Since $f\in C_0$ so $|f(x)|\leq \|f\|_\infty<\infty$ for all $x$ and so $\displaystyle\sum \frac{|f(r_n)|}{2^n}\leq \|f\|_\infty$. Hence $I$ is welldefined. It's clear that $I$ is a linear functional. Now let $\|f\|=1$, then $|f(x)|\leq 1$ for all $x$ and then $|\int_0^1 fdm|\leq1$ It means that $\|I\|=sup_{\|f\|=1}~ |I(f)|\leq \|f\|_\infty+1$. Therefore $I$ is bounded. **(But I couldn't find $\|I\|$)**. Since $I$ is bounded on $C_0(R)$ by theorem 6.19 of the book Real & complex Rudin there exists unique regular complex measure $\mu$ s.t $I(f)=\int fd\mu ~~\forall f\in C_0$ **(But I couldn't say $\mu$ is a Radon measure)**.
2. $f\in L^1(\nu) \Longleftrightarrow \int|f|d\nu<\infty \Longleftrightarrow \int|f|d\mu-\int|f|dm <\infty \Longleftrightarrow f\in L^1(\mu)\cap l^1(m)$.

Comment: To determine $||I||$, consider whether your argument gives an upper bound on it. On the other hand if you take $f_n$ to be a sequence in $C_0$ that converges pointwise to the constant function $f(x)=1$ you can derive a lower bound.